# How to set different bounds for indexed variable in Gurobipy

Tags: python, optimization, gurobi

I am trying to create an indexed variable using Gurobipy like so:

```
m.addVars(5, vtype='I', name="x", lb = 0, ub = 1000)
```

How can I set a new lower and upper bound for each separate element in this variable?

For example, lb = 0 and ub = 1000 for 1st index, lb = 100 and ub = 300 for 2nd index, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass lists for the lower and upper bounds:

```py
lbs = [0, 100, 200, 300, 400]
ubs = [1000, 300, 900, 900, 900]
x = m.addVars(5, name="x", lb=lbs, ub=ubs)
```

Note that `lbs` and `ubs` can also be numpy arrays.